# How to control the WebTau report

Tags: rest, testing, test-reporting, webtau

When I first used WebTau it would produce a report file in the project directory where the WebTau tests were being run.  Tests that use WebTau are no longer generating a report.

- Is there a way to (manually) conrol when the report is produced?
- Can I specify an output directory for this report?

Also, there is another question as to how I managed to change things and the report is no longer being generated automatically?  I have moved some common code patterns into a TestingSupport project, because I found a bunch of tests were almost cut-n-paste at this ealry stage.  There's no report file appearing in another directory though.

Another potential explaination is that I commented-out the `@WebTau` annotation on my test Class.  I did that when I moved REST calling patterns to a library class.  Everything works fine, of course there's no report.  I'm guessing that is going to be a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@WebTau` annotation is essential for JUnit5 to generate the report. You need to annotate any class that you want to participate in the report.

Alternatively you can try to register global WebTau extension `org.testingisdocumenting.webtau.junit5.WebTauJunitExtension` following this JUnit5 guide: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions#1-automatic-extension-registration

Use [reportPath](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/configuration/options#reportPath) config value to change the report location

It can be specified using [config file](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/getting-started/configuration#config-file) or system property override or using [environment variable](https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/configuration/options#WEBTAU_REPORT_PATH)